# Calling accept() gives errorno 14 bad address

Tags: c, sockets

I am creating a client and a server application and I am currently trying to establish a connection. Whenever the client tries to connect to the server the server call to accept returns -1. When I examined the `errno` that was set from accept() it was 14 which stands for bad address. 
My code for creating the socket and accepting is as follows

```
  //create socket
  if((listenfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create server socket! errno %i: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
      exit(-1);
    }

  //bind to the socket
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);


  if( bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))<0)
    {
      printf("Server bind failure errno %i: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
      exit(-1);
    }

  // Turn 'listenfd' to a listening socket. Listen queue size is 5. 

  if(listen(listenfd,5) < 0)
    {
      printf("Server listen failure errno %i: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
      exit(-1);
    }
  while(1)
    {
      //accept connections
      if(newsock=accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr,sizeof(clientaddr)<0))
    {
      printf("Server accept failure errno %i: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
      exit(-1);
    }
      int ch=fork();
      if(ch<0)
    {
      printf("Fork failure errno %i: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
      exit(-1);
    }
      else if (ch==0)
    {
      char buff[100];

      int rc;
      rc=recv(listenfd,buff,sizeof(buff),0);
      if(rc<0)
        {
          printf("Receive failure errno %i: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
          exit(-1);
        }

      printf("%s",buff);
      exit(-1);
    }

    }
```

What am I doing wrong in my server code?

Comment: recv() does not null terminate the received data ( it does return how many bytes are in the received data) so this line: printf("%s",buff); will produced random results.  suggest adding line: buff[rc] = '\0'; before printf()

Comment: @user3629249 it's ok with me since I am using strtok to split the data (for example it's functions(arguments) so I tokenize with ( to get the function and with ) to get the arguments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(newsock=accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr,sizeof(clientaddr)<0))
```

In your code `sizeof(clientaddr)<0` evaluates to 0 and passed to `accept` function as last argument. Replace with:

```
int addrlen;
...
addrlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
if((newsock=accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr,&addrlen))<0)
```

Comment: stupid parenthesis......
Now I get a warning about pointer to integer without a cast and it still is not working

Comment: Just note: `newsock = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr,&addrlen); if ( newsock < 0 ) {...}` performs exactly like one-line version and much more readable and error-prone. But this is an individual preference.

Comment: That's what I ended up using, I am used to using C# in visual studio and errors like this would not happen (the existence of booleans, warnings and errors appearing as you write etc etc) anws, thanks :D